# how to show my app in list of browsers on click of a link in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

When a user clicks on a link, I want my app to show up in the list of browsers in which he can open the app. What should I write in my app's manifest for this to work?

Comment: @nemesv I think your linked question differs from Puck's one. That question is about open own app when user clicks a link in the browser. But Puck's question is about showing own app in list of browsers which handle links.

Comment: @yrajabi if you think the linked question is different then why posted the same answer what somebody already provided on the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5563246/872395. I think if the same answer answers two questions then the two question is duplicate...

Comment: @nemesv Didn't you notice the different?! your linked question has this answer:  <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" /> which differs from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest xml inside your activity tag:

```
        <intent-filter> 
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```